# WPF DataGrid: check certain columns and update

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

In my WPF application I have a DataGrid. For example, the one in the picture: [image]

In the first row, Name is a0 and Value is 0x12 (hexadecimal), lets call it a0[Value]. So what I need to do is make sure that: **a0[Value] < a1[Value] < a2[Value]**. Also that **b0[Value] < b1[Value] < b2[Value]**, and that **c0[Value] < c1[Value]**. I can't depend on the fact that Name is always the first column and Value is always the 4th column. I know that the Name column will always have the values a0,a1,a2,b0,b1,b2,c0,c1 but I don't know in which order. And to make it even more complicated, if for example, **a0[Value] > a1[Value]**, I need to change a1[Value] so that **a1[Value]=a0[Value]**. I really need your help.

Comment: Ahhhh....and for this confusion what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried to make different arrays for each set of names (a,b,c) and run over this dataGrid for a million times to fill up the arrays, then check if they are sorted.. it's a long and ugly code and I got stuck at updating the dataGrid if the array is not sorted.. @DhavalPatel

Comment: After receiving your *I don't know how to check if the values of specific names are in correct order and fix them at the same time* comment, I have voted to close this question because this question now appears to be off-topic because [*Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, we don't manipulate UI elements. Instead, we manipulate data elements. Therefore, your problem becomes a whole lot easier if you data bind a collection to your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property and manipulate your data *before* you display it:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />
```

You should always represent your data with custom classes (that implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)) because it makes everything so much easier. From your example, we can see that your class (let's name it `Item`) should have four properties: `Name`, `SomeCol`, `Blah` and `Value`. Then your collection should be of type `ObservableCollection<Item>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set
    {
        items = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is sort your data. There are many different ways of achieving this and with differing levels of complication, but using `LinQ` can help. First, we want to order the data by the first letter in the `Name` column, which is now represented by the `Name` property in your class and then you need to sort the items by the `Value` property. I can't check this right now, but this should do the trick, or get you somewhere close:

```
using System.Linq; 

Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(Items.OrderBy(i => i.Name.FirstOrDefault()).
    ThenBy(i => i.Value))
```

Comment: The DataGrid is binded to a DataTable. I don't need to sort, but to fix values that make it not sorted...

Comment: My answer (minus the sorting) still holds. You will still benefit from supplying the `DataGrid` with data in custom classes, rather than a `DataGrid`. However, it seems that all you need to do is to iterate through the rows in your `DataTable` and adjust the data values in the relevant columns... I don't see any problem with that. What *is* your problem with doing that?

Comment: I don't know how to check if the values of specific names are in correct order and fix them at the same time.. if the value where the name is a1 bigger than the value where the name is a2, I should copy the value of a1 to a2. And the same for the b's and c's..

Comment: *I don't know how to check if the values of specific names are in correct order and fix them at the same time*... then I'm sorry, but you are *not* qualified to use this website, which is for  *professional and enthusiast programmers* and *not* for absolute beginners. While we are happy to help developers with specific programming problems, it has been deemed that teaching absolute beginners is far too broad in scope for this website.

Comment: I am not a beginner at all. I have a solution and I'm just looking for a more elegant and effective way to do it.